# How to pull numbers from a string/file name in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, date

Hopefully somebody can help me with this.. or at least point me in the right direction.

First off, I have a bunch of files with names such as:

```
vendor.2012-07-25
vendor.2012-07-25 2
ven_dor.2012-05-18
ven_dor.2012-05-18 2
```

Basically a vendor name (Sometimes one word, sometimes two with an underscore) + (period ".") + (year) + (month) + (day). Year, month, day are separated by (-). Possibly multiple files with the same name, denoted by a 2/3/4 etc after the date.

I obtain these as strings by doing file.getName(); where 'file' is the selected file from a JFileChooser

Then I need to chart some of the data based on date. Should I try to split the initial file name string by a "." first, so that the vendor and date are separated, and then split/divide up the remaining part by "-" to have the individual values for year/month/day?

I was thinking this could be a regex thing, but I'm pretty weak in that area.. so the double splitting is what I came up with. Anybody have input or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
String s = "vendor.2012-07-25 2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^.]+)\\.(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) ?(\\d?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  String vendorName = m.group(1);
  String year = m.group(2);
  String month = m.group(3);
  String day = m.group(4);
  String multipleFiles = m.groupCount() > 4 ? m.group(5) : "";
  System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s", vendorName, year, month, day, multipleFiles);
}
```

Each expression wrapped with parentheses `()` is called a *capturing group*, and it basically tells the regex engine to save its content, so that it can be retrieved later on.

In sum, here's what each capturing group does:

1. `([^.]+)` - Everything but a dot (`.`), so we are basically capturing the vendor name part;
2. `(\\d{4})` - `\d` matches a digit. `\d{4}` matches `4` digits (year);
3. `(\\d{2})` - Month;
4. `(\\d{2})` - Day;
5. `(\\d?)` - Matches an optional (`?`) last digit.

If you want to parse the date part as a `java.Util.Date` instance, you can use a single capturing group for it, and then use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^.]+)\\.(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}) ?(\\d?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  String vendorName = m.group(1);
  String dateString = m.group(2);
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String multipleFiles = m.groupCount() > 2 ? m.group(3) : "";
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I'm not sure which route I want to go yet; regex or normal splitting. But either way, this is good information.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

- `String.split` on the `.` (it will probably require escaping).  Take the `dotSplitString[1]` as being the part after `vendor.` or `ven_dor.`
- Split that part on space  (`spaceSplitString`).
- Parse the first part using `DateFormat.parse(String)` to get a `Date`
- If the 2nd part (of the `spaceSplitString`) is present, use `Integer.parseInt(spaceSplitString[1])`

Comment: Excellent, that's basically what I was thinking of doing. Thanks for clarifying :D

Comment: String[1] will be the date part not the vendor part. Subsequently, Integer.parseInt(string[1]) will throw an exception.

Comment: @km1 *"String[1] will be the date part not the vendor part."*  Exactly.  The `vendor`/`ven_dor` string seems useless, so my approach ignores it and goes directly to the date.

Answer (score 0):

[Java API String Tokenizer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

What you can do is:

```
tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(file.getName(), ".");
tokenizer.nextElement();
```

you get the picture, Or you can use Scanner to parse it as well

Answer (score 0):

I tend to make use of StringTokenizers in my code a lot. To tokenize the above example you could use something akin to the following:

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(filename,".-");  //tokenizes both on '.' and '-'
String name = tok.nextToken();
int year = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
int month = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
int day = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
int cnt = 1; //default one copy of the file
if(tok.hasMoreTokens()){
     cnt = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
}
```

...and so on.

However I endorse the use of the regex solution above, if not only because it looks less comprehensible to a layman. Just including this here for completeness.